# How do I "Enable Wi-Fi" on my toolbar if the option disappeared?

Tags: wireless

Hi so yesterday I was trying to update my wifi drivers but when I rebooted, the option to "Enable wi-fi" disappeared on my toolbar? How do I make it show up again?

I have Qualcomm Atheros QC6174a btw.

Thanks.